# Python 3. Как передать значения ячеек из excell файла в массив?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Общая задача, это взять данные из одного файла, некоторые изменить и записать в другой файл.

Что имеем: 
Есть Excell файл в котором записана информация в виде столбцов.

1. Порядковый номер - IdNumber
2. Счёт  - account
3. Количество - ClearPosition
4. Максимальная цена - MaxPrice
5. Минимальная цена  - MinPrice
6. Продажа - OrderSell
7. Покупка - OrderBuy
8. Price - пока пустая переменная.
9. Tool - пока пустая переменная.

Например: Порядковый номер 1 Счёт 000111 Количество 2 Максимальная цена 100 Минимальная цена 50
Порядковый номер 2 Счёт 000222 Количество -5 Максимальная цена 100 Минимальная цена 50
Мне нужно, чтобы из файла Excell считывались эти данные и записывались в строчку в текстовый документ но с условием: Если количество ClearPosition указано положительное 2 то берём значение из MinPrice, подставляем его в Price и дополнительно берем значение из OrderSell  т.о. запись в текстовом документе должны выглядеть так:

```
1;счёт=000111;Количество=1;Цена=50;Продажа;
```

Для второго примера с отрицательным количеством всё так же, только берется значение из MaxPrice и значение из OrderBuy

```
2;счёт=000222;Количество=5;Цена=100;Покупка;
```

Я так подозреваю, что данные из Excell я должен поместить в массив и из массива уже присваивать переменным, далее значения этих переменных я записываю в txt файл. Затем переменным присваиваются следующие значения и опять записываются в txt файл. Подскажите, как мне эти данные передавать в массив? Мне можно данные из всех ячеек передавать в один массив или лучше в разные? Как передавать данные в массив из конкретной ячейки?
Если кто-то скинет пример кода буду очень благодарен.
p.s. просьба советовать самый простой вариант решения, красота кода не важна быстродействие тоже.

Входные данные:

```
IdNumber account   tool ClearPosition  MaxPrice  MinPrice
   1     0001GJ    SRU8      1           100        50
   2     0002IA    SiU8     -1           200       100
   3     0003I6    SRU8      0           300       200
```

Попробовал через csv файл данные в массив получать. Такой код смог получить

```
import csv
with open('position.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    data_read = [row for row in reader]
print(data_read)
```

Теперь в результате получаю такое:

```
[['0001GJ;SRU8;1;100;50'], ['0002IA;SiU8;-1;200;100'], ['0003I6;SRU8;0;300;200']]
```

Как из этого результата, теперь я могу взять значение '0001GJ и присвоить его переменной account' потом взять 'SRU8 и присвоить переменную tool' и т.д.

Comment: Сначала считайте из excel в массив/список, потом обработайте данные и сохраните

Comment: Приведите пример входных и выходных данных. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Теперь выгружаю данные в txt файл. Входные данные выглядят вот так:            
0001GJ SRU8 1 100 50
0002IA SiU8        -1 200 100
0003I6 SRU8 0 300 200  читаю файл вот так                                                  
    'with open('position.txt') as file:  
    var_list = filter(str.strip, file)  
    var_list = list(map(str, var_list))  
print(var_list)' получаю в таком виде ['0001GJ\tSRU8\t1\t100\t50\n', '0002IA\tSiU8\t-1\t200\t100\n', '0003I6\tSRU8\t0\t300\t200\n']  мне нужно чтобы каждое значение из строки было в отдельной ячейке массива прим: ['0001GJ', 'SRU8','1','100', 50]

Comment: Все-таки у вас другой разделитель: `delimiter=','` -> `delimiter=';'`

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю использовать библиотеку `openpyx` с ней работать, она получше `csv`

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter, column_index_from_string

Sale = load_workbook(
    "path/excell_name.xlsx")
# get_sheet_names() - выводит список с названием листов,
sheets_name = Sale.get_sheet_names()
for k in range(1):
# for k in range(len(sheets_name)):
    sheet = Sale[sheets_name[k]]
    for i in range(2, 100): # беру со второй так как в первой идут названия столбцов
        IdNumber = sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value
        account = sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value
        ClearPosition = sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).value
        MaxPrice = sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).value
        MinPrice = sheet.cell(row=i, column=5).value
        OrderSell = sheet.cell(row=i, column=6).value
        OrderBuy = sheet.cell(row=i, column=7).value
        Price = sheet.cell(row=i, column=8).value
        Tool = sheet.cell(row=i, column=9).value
        if int(ClearPosition) > 0:
            a = [IdNumber, ClearPosition,MinPrice, OrderSell]
        else:
            b = [IdNumber, ClearPosition, MaxPrice. OrderBuy]
        print(a)
        print('_____')
        print(b)
```

еще советую прочесть статью `https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/331998/` для большего понимания работы с данными из Excel на Python-е.